# How to delete specific value from a column in SQL row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in SQL. Currently, I am working with a SQL database that has two columns. The first column specifies the id. The second column specifies a list of people separated by the delimiter "@d@" So, the column looks something like "John@d@Jack@d@Prince"

I need to delete a specific name from this list. Suppose, I am deleting prince from the list. I want my row to look like John@d@Jack after the delete operation. I was researching solutions for this procedure and I found couple resources. I learned about this approach "UPDATE TABLE SET columnName = null WHERE YourCondition" As a result, I can change the whole column to null, but I don't know how to retain the string and only delete the specified value.

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Storing lists of names in a delimited string is just not the SQLish way of storing multiple values.  If you are learning SQL, it is even more important to do things "right" from the SQL perspective.

Comment: Someone made a very bad call when using that delimiter. I've seen some crazy delimiters in my time, but that one's deliberately obnoxious. Sorry you got thrown onto a project that's so sadly broken. This is a good learning experience though. Hopefully you never inflict something like this on someone else in your career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace function

```
update yourTable set yourField = replace(replace(yourField, 'Prince', ''), '@@' , '@') where yourCondition;
```

First replace "delete" the name you want to, second replace "delete" deleted name's delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken the command you are looking for is

```
UPDATE TABLE set columnName = "John@d@Jack" WHERE YourCondition
```

Or do you want a more general approach?

Comment: I need a more general approach because I don't know what is already present in the row. I have a variable that holds the value I want to delete from this column. Therefore, I have var variable=Prince. I want to run a SQL query such that the new column would look like John@d@Jack. However, I don't know whats already present in the column, but it is guaranteed that the variable will be present in the column list

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using:

```
update t
    set list = trim(both '@' from replace(concat('@', list, '@'), concat('@', 'prince', '@'), '@'))
    where concat('@', list, '@') like concat('%@', 'prince', '@%');
```

You can replace `'prince'` with a variable or whatever you want to replace.